# End of Stream Exception when trying to add list<> items to listbox1 from binary file

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listbox, binaryreader

My project stores phone numbers into a list<> and saves them into a .bin file:

```
private void savebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sv = new SaveFileDialog();
        sv.Filter = "Binary files (*.bin)|*.bin|All files(*.*)|*.*";
        sv.Title = "Save File";
        sv.FilterIndex = 2;
        sv.RestoreDirectory = true;
        sv.InitialDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(@"F:\Computer Technology Skills\Programming 35\Module 1\ICA10\ICA10\bin\Debug");
        if (sv.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(sv.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                BinaryWriter file = new BinaryWriter(fs);
                //         System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sv.FileName.ToString());
                var message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, PhoneNum);
                file.Write(message);
                file.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
            }

        }
    }
```

Then pressing the load button is supposed to delete the items currently in the listbox1 to replace them with whatever items were in the bin file on each line.

```
private void loadbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
        string databyte = null;
        long iNumInts = 0;

        od.RestoreDirectory = true;
        od.InitialDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(@"F:\Computer Technology Skills\Programming 35\Module 1\ICA10\ICA10\bin\Debug");
        if (od.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(od.FileName, FileMode.Open);
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs))
                {

                    iNumInts = fs.Length / sizeof(int);
                    for (int i = 0; i < iNumInts; i++)
                    {
                        databyte = reader.ReadString(); //Endofstreamexception
                        listBox1.Items.Add(databyte);

                    }
                        fs.Close();
                        reader.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, when I load the file I saved, the items are all stuck on the first index of the listbox1 and I receive an endofstream exception.

I'm a bit confused here since my notes didn't help much and other stack overflow questions I found were examples using integers or arrays. I switched from streamwriter to binarywriter which helped a lot, but any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the `StreamReader` for this.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(od.Filename))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        listbox1.Items.Add(line);
    }
}
```

You can also use [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) which does it all for you (if you're using .NET 4 or above).

Comment: thanks; i guess keep binary reader for ints and bytes and streamreader for strings.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your save code, it looks like you are writing the phone numbers as a single string with a newline delimiter between them.  In the read code you are trying to read them as individual strings with the ReadString method.

One string out equals one string in. In other words, if you write them all out as one string, then read them all in as one string.  Then you could use string.split and get the individual numbers.